# overcome single tcp connection speed limit

Tags: tcp, udp, vpn, tunnel

i am a bit stuck and need some hints please.

My ISP seems to throttle single connections to 400 kbps no matter if i use VPN/ssh tunnel/proxy or direct connect. For file transfer its not a problem, i can use lftp with multiple connections which gets me to 1 Gbps in up or down.

I have a few vps and a dedicated server which i would like to use as a tunnel to overcome this limitation. I have already tried wireguard/openvpn/cloak/shadowsocks. Is there anything else what creates maybe multiple tcp or udp connections to get things going?

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: How about contacting your ISP about this issue? If you pay for more than 400kbps, make them provide more than 400kbps.

Comment: they blame it on the other end as speedtest shows good speeds in both directions. All big websites seem to be whitelisted with them.

Comment: This is not a question related to programming, i.e. off-topic here and more on-topic on superuser.com. But to give some help: a real VPN or SSH tunnel is intransparent to the ISP, i.e. it cannot limit the bandwidth of single connections inside but only the whole VPN/SSH tunnel. If you can run multiple connections within this tunnel which in total exceed the observed bandwidth limit (like in your example with lftp), then the problem is not bandwidth limiting by the ISP but somewhere else.